# Unity: Change Text with Time (Text Flashes)

Tags: unity, text

I am trying to display instructions within the Unity game. The idea is to have the instructions appear over time. For example, "instruction 1" then wait 5 seconds and show "instruction 2" instead of instruction 1 (on the same spot, in this case, I am changing the "message" variable in the code to change the instructions). This code does change the instructions but the problem is that it does it in a haphazard fashion. It appears that "instruction 1" is replaced with "instruction 2" and then it reverts back to "instruction 1" within a second and then back to "instruction 2" so instead of just 1-appearing->1-disappearing->2-appearing->etc in a smooth fashion, it does this weird flashing thing before proceeding to the next instruction. How could I fix this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Growing : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text instructions;
    public string message;

    void Start () { 
         instructions.text = message;
    }

    void Update () {

         Instructions();

         //other code to begin moving a game object
    }

    IEnumerator Instructions() {
        //run instructions
        message = "GET READY FOR YOUR FOCUSED BREATHING EXERCISE";
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
        message = "MAKE SURE YOUR BODY IS COMFORTABLE";
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or the coroutine method:

You were almost correct, what you needed to do was wrap the `Instructions()` invocation inside a `StartCoroutine()` call. This lets Unity add the method to the task scheduler.  Then, make sure you call it only once, either by putting it in `Start()` (as I've done below) or inside some other conditional that prevents multiple copies of the coroutine from being created simultaneously.

```
void Start () {

     StartCoroutine(Instructions());

     //other code to begin moving a game object
}

IEnumerator Instructions() {
    //run instructions
    message = "GET READY FOR YOUR FOCUSED BREATHING EXERCISE";
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
    message = "MAKE SURE YOUR BODY IS COMFORTABLE";
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You start a new coroutine every time you call "update". YOu are not the first to ask this, and I'm not the first to answer, so let me just quote someone else:

> Yes, coroutines run independently, like separate threads. When you
> start a coroutine, an instance of it is created and starts running. If
> you start the same coroutine again, another instance is created and
> runs independently of the other, and so on. This is a blessing in some
> special cases, but much more often may become a curse: if you start a
> coroutine each Update, for example (a very common error), a new
> instance will be created each frame, crowding the memory and eating
> the CPU time in a few minutes
>
> http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/309613/calling-startcoroutine-multiple-times-seems-to-sta.html

As a starting point, try the following instead:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Growing : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Text instructions;
    float instructionStartTime = -1;

    void Start () { 
        LaunchInstructions();
    }

    void LaunchInstructions()
    {
        instructionStartTime = Time.time;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (instructionStartTime > 0 && Time.time >= instructionStartTime)
        {
            if (Time.time - instructionStartTime < 5)
                instructions.text = "GET READY FOR YOUR FOCUSED BREATHING EXERCISE";
            else if (Time.time - instructionStartTime < 10)
                instructions.text = "MAKE SURE YOUR BODY IS COMFORTABLE";
            else
            {
                instructionStartTime = -1;
                instructions.text = "";
            }
        }
        //other code to begin moving a game object
    }
```